# Validation using Composite Pattern

Tags: java, android

Can somebody please explain how can I use the composite design pattern to validate a registration form in android. In this form I have 8 EditText fields (Ussername, Password, Password re-enter, City, Gender, Age, Phone number, Email). I have already validated it using this code

```
    public boolean validateInput() {

    boolean validated = true;

    if (mUserValues.getCity() == null || mUserValues.getCity().isEmpty()) {
        mCityEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error));
        validated = false;
    }

    if (mUserValues.getEmail() == null || mUserValues.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("mEmail", "in mEmail");

        mEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error));
        validated = false;
    }

    if (mUserValues.getPassword() == null
            || mUserValues.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
        mPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error));
        validated = false;
    }

    if (mUserValues.getPasswordCheck() == null
            || mUserValues.getPasswordCheck().isEmpty()) {
        mPasswordConfirm.setError(getString(R.string.error));
        validated = false;

    }

    if (mUserValues.getPassword() != null
            && mUserValues.getPasswordCheck() != null
            && !mPasswordEditText.getText().toString()
                    .equals(mPasswordEditText.getText().toString())) {
        mPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.pass_check));
        mPasswordConfirm.setError(getString(R.string.pass_check));
        validated = false;
    }

    if (mUserValues.getSex() == null || mUserValues.getSex().isEmpty()) {
        mSex.setError(getString(R.string.error));
        validated = false;
    }

    if (mUserValues.getPhoneNumber() == 0) {
        mPhone.setError(getString(R.string.error));
        validated = false;
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Constants.EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mEmail.getText().toString());
    mEmailCheck = matcher.matches();

    if (mEmailCheck == false) {
        mEmail.setError(getString(R.string.email_valid));
        validated = false;
    }

    if (mUserValues.getUsername().length() <= 2) {
        mUsername.setError(getString(R.string.username_check));
        validated = false;
    }

    if ((mUserValues.getAge() < 18 || mUserValues.getAge() > 150)
            && mUserValues.getAge() > 0) {
        mAge.setError(getString(R.string.age_check));
        validated = false;
    }

    return validated;

}
```

A friend of mine told me that it can be done using the composite design pattern, but I don't really understand how can that be done.
I will be really grateful if somebody could explain.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Patterns are great, but if it's already working for you and you don't need to use the pattern, then don't use it. "My friend says" is not a reason to change your program. Now, if you intend for this form to be able to change or be dynamically created at run time, then perhaps you have a good reason for using a Composite pattern to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently inspecting the state of an object (e.g. `if (mUserValues.getCity() == null)`) from the outside. And if you add a field to `mUserValues` you'll also have to add code to handle that field to `validateInput`.

That is bad encapsulation / strong coupling according to the OO principles. That object should handle / validate it's internal state itself (or know another object that can do it -> composite pattern).

I'd move the validation inside the object in a first step (e.g. `if (!mUserValues.validateCity())`).

After that you'd still need to know about the internals of your `mUserValues` object on the ouside - e.g. know that there is a city field to validate.

So in a next step you could get rid of that as well. The result could look roughly like

```
public boolean validateInput() {
    boolean validated = true;
    for (ValidatableField field : mUserValues.getValidatableFields()) {
        if (!field.isValid()) {
            field.showError(R.string.error);
            validated = false;
        }
    }
    return validated;
}
```

Now the `validateInput` code is completely independant of the amount of fields and how they have to be validated. Adding a filed does not require to change anything in there.

Wether you use composition or inheritance is up to you. But using [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is a good thing.